# Преобразовать JS массив в другой вид

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как правильно преобразовать массив вида:

```
var Orders = [
   {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Order_1',
    city: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'SPB'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Order_2',
    city: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'SPB'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Order_3',
    city: {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Moscow'
    }
  }
]
```

Во что-то такое:

```
var cities = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'SPB',
    orders: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Order_1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Order_2'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Moscow',
    orders: [
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Order_1'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Сейчас использую такой вариант преобразования:

```
   var Orders = [
       {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Order_1',
        city: {
          id: 1,
          title: 'SPB'
        }
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Order_2',
        city: {
          id: 1,
          title: 'SPB'
        }
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Order_3',
        city: {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Moscow'
        }
      }
    ]

    const transformArray = (arr) => {
        const map = new Map();                  
        arr.forEach( (el) => {
            map.set(el.city, []);
        });
        arr.forEach( (el) => {
            if (map.has(el.city)) {
                let value = map.get(el.city);
                value.push({
                    id: el.id,
                    title: el.title
                });
            }
        });                    
        let structure = [];
        map.forEach( (value, key) => {
            structure.push({
                id: key.id,
                title: key.title,
                cities: value 
            });
        });
        return structure
    }    

    const Cities = transformArray(Orders);
    console.log(Cities);
```

Comment: Знаем. Написать код. Но я не вижу ваших попыток это сделать

Comment: это Вам нужен reduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерный вариант с `reduce`, о котором я писал в комментариях, чтобы избежать вложенных циклов используем для свертки `Object`, можно было бы и `Set`

```js
var Orders = [{
    id: 1, title: 'Order_1',
    city: { id: 1,title: 'SPB'}
},{
    id: 2, title: 'Order_2',
    city: {id: 1,title: 'SPB' }
}, {
    id: 3, title: 'Order_3',
    city: { id: 2,title: 'Moscow'}
}];


let process = d => Object.values(d.reduce((a, e) => {
  
  //  если идентификатора города нет в аккумуляторе
  if (!a[e.city.id]) { 
    // создаем город в аккумуляторе
    a[e.city.id] = e.city;
    // добавим к нему поле с массивом заказов
    e.city.orders = [];
  }

  // Ищем в аккумуляторе город и добавляем в него заказ
  a[e.city.id].orders.push(e); 

  // удаляем информацию о городе
  delete e.city

  return a;

}, {}))

console.log(process(Orders));
```

Answer (score 3):

С использованием map и filter можно сделать

```js
var Orders = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Order_1',
        city: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'SPB'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Order_2',
        city: {
            id: 1,
            title: 'SPB'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Order_3',
        city: {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Moscow'
        }
    }
];
var cities = Array.from(new Set(Orders.map((a) => a.city.id)))  //Получаем уникальные ID городов
.map(city_id => {  //Строим новый объект города
    return {
        id: city_id,   //Ид города
        title: Orders.find(s => s.city.id == city_id).city.title,  //Название города
        //Выбиараем ордера по ID города и вовращаем новый объект без свойства city
        orders: Array.from(Orders.filter(v => v.city.id == city_id).map(b=>{return {id:b.id,title:b.title}})) 
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(cities,null,"  "));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваш код работает. Если я правильно понимаю, то на каждой итерации будет запускаться дополнительный обход массива? Не будет ли это критично, если размер подобного массива будет составлять порядка 200 объектов? Я хочу сделать это преобразование чтобы избавиться от дополнительного запроса в бд и, соответственно, хотелось бы, чтобы преобразование было производительнее оного.

Comment: Не совсем понял, о какой итерации идет речь. Алгорит такой: 1. Выбираете все данные из БД. 2. Запускаете преобразование. В таком случае проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Я имел в виду. Не будет ли преобразование с вложенными циклами медленнее чем отдельный запрос в бд? Просто есть вариант дополнительно выбрать необходимую мне структуру прямо из бд (использую graphQl) вместо преобразования.